# Nsight skips (ignores) over break points in VS10 Cuda when debugging remotely but if debug locally on the target machine it works fine

Tags: cuda, gpu, nsight, cuda-gdb

when I debugging my cuda project remotely on the host it ignore breakpoints but execute completely . but when I debug my project locally on the target machine it works fine .

I checked my driver version it was 301.42 and my nsight version is 2.2

my target machine has Geforce 8600GT and host machine has Geforce 6200 turboCache .I think that my host machine's GPU is not TCC enable.

nsight Analysis activity work fine in both locally and remotely but cuda debugging is work only in local mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a driver version problem. My experience is that not every driver version works with Nsight. Currently i am running the latest driver version (310.90) and Nsight 3.0 is working fine locally and also remotely.
When in doubt, use the driver version that is listed on the Nsight download page.

Comment: deer @RoBik tank you for your answer I checked my driver version it was 301.42 and my nsight version is 2.2 and according to its release note this version is compatible version driver

Comment: @farzad: could you please describe your setup in more detail? Do both computers have a CUDA capable GPU? If yes, are both running the correct driver version? Do you have Nsight installed on both of them?

Comment: :my target machine has Geforce 8600GT and host machine has Geforce 6200 turboCache .I think that my host machine's GPU is not TCC enable. nsight Analysis activity work fine in both locally and remotely

Comment: @farzad: TCC means "Tesla Compute Cluster", that is a mode available on Tesla and Quadro cards. What you probably meant was that the Geforce 6200 turboCache is not a CUDA capable card and that is correct. If the local debugging on the target machine works correctly than the problem is most likely with your host setup. Are you absolutely sure that when debugging on the host, your kernel is actually executing without errors? Also are the source code and the project settings the same when debugging remotely as when debugging locally?

Comment: Maybe you could also try to upgrade to CUDA 5 and Nsight 3.0 and see if you the problem persists.

Comment: thank you for your help, yes you are right, but I can debug my project locally without any problem and when I debug the project remotely on host it execute properly but skip over any breakpoints in the kernel and exit from debugging immediately . even nsight analysis activity work fine remotely .I think nsight 2.2 is the latest version that has been released for visual studio 2010 ! I cant find the nsight 3.0  !!

Comment: is there any special point in host configuration that I probably forgot it ? I setup secure connection between host and target

Comment: :am I build the project on host machine? or on target machine and bring project that already  is built on target to the host machine and debug it ?

Comment: Nsight 3.0 is not released yet. If you want to get early access to this version you need to have an "Registered Developer" account. If you already have an account you can download Nsight 3.0 from this address: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/nsight-visual-studio-edition-early-access

Comment: The only thing in the Nsight configuration that i need to change when debugging remotely is the "connection name" option and for some projects i also set the "working directory" if the project is dependent on a specific location. When debugging remotely, the program is compiled on the host. When you push the "Start CUDA Dabuggign" button, Nsight connects to the Nsight Monitor running on the target machine and copies (synchronizes) the compiled files to the target machine and after that the application is executed on the target.

Comment: dear RoBiK @RoBiK I cant bulid my project on the host! do you know whats wrong ?

Comment: if you are unable to compile on the host than it is clear that Nsight debugging can not work. What exactly is Visual Studio reporting when you try to build the project? What do the error messages say?

Answer (score 0):

that problem was because I bring project that  already has built on my target to the host , but when I clean the project on host and rebuild it it dosent work because of one link error 
I search the link error and find the solution

solution was doing flowing instruction :
project -> propertiy->configuration properties->linker->general -> enable Incremental linking
and update it to NO(/INCREMENT:NO)

and then debugging is work remotely

I am sorry about my ignorance :D